# Background images?

Tags: html, background

I want to put a couple of images for a background.
The point is as you scroll down to see a different image.
Right now as I fill my page, the image is stretching and don't want that.
Most of the answers include javascript but I don't know it.

[this is my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Zvk.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, unfortunately you'll need to learn new things at some point. Start with google and [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) on how to do what you want to help along the way, and come back when you run into specific problems. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sudgest adding several sections/divs depending on the purpose to your body with the height equil to image height. Then, set the background image of each section/div.
HTML:

```
<body>
  <section id="section-1"></section>
  <section id="section-2"></section>
  <section id="section-3"></section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#section-1 {
  height: [image 1 height];
  background-image: url([yourimage1url]);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#section-2 {
  height: [image 2 height];
  background-image: url([yourimage2url]);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#section-3 {
  height: [image 3 height];
  background-image: url([yourimage3url]);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```